# If $x \mapsto \int_A f(x-t) \, d\mu(t)$ vanishes identically, do we have that $\mu=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $A \subset \mathbb R$ is a compact set and let $\mu$ be a complex regular Borel measure on $A$. Further, let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ be a non-zero function with a certain decay (for instance, assume that $f$ is a Schwartz function). Further, assume that
$$
\int_A f(x-t) \, d\mu(t) = 0 \ \ \forall x \in \mathbb R.
$$
I want to conclude that $\mu = 0$. My approach would be to take the Fourier transform of the map
$$
x \mapsto \int_A f(x-t) \, d\mu(t)
$$
which gives $\hat f \hat \mu = 0$ and then use that $\hat f$ does not vanish identically and $\hat \mu$ is entire. Hence $\hat \mu = 0$ which gives $\mu=0$. My problem is that I don't know if all these steps are justified since I'm working with an arbitrary complex regular Borel measure.

Answer (score 3):

Of course $f$ has to decay.  Example...
$A = [0,1]$, $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure, $f(x) = \sin(2\pi x)$, to get
$\int_0^1 f(x-t)\;dt = 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: But what if $f$ decays? Do we know if the above result holds? Can you suggest something to read in the literature?